# Swagger error .Net core web api. Unsupported Media Type. Consumes["application/json"] vs upload xlsx file

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Swagger in my .NET Core Web Api project.
I am uploading an Excel file (.xlsx) to the system on my one Controller. But I get **Unsupported Media Type** error when uploading files because of the `Consumes["application/json"]` line.

[image]

Swagger doesn't work even when `Consumes["application/json"]` line is removed.

[image]
[image]

I added the `Consumes["application/json"]` code because I got a Swagger authorize error.

Comment: Can you add the endpoint definition in your controller?

Comment: Yeah. I don't think the problem comes from there. Everything looks correct.

Comment: I added the latest stable `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.2.3` to my asp.net core api project, initial the configurations and created a file upload api, then I visit `https://localhost:<port>/swagger`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Adding `Consumes["multipart/form-data"]` to the top of each function to upload xlsx fixed the problem.